# Decimal Format in Java

Tags: java, decimalformat

i was looking for an answer in here, but i couldn't find it, if there is other post talking about it, I'm sorry, but well, my answer is an easy one im sure of it but I cant see it, how can I format a decimal like:

```
 7.9820892389040892803E-05
```

And I want to format that number to keep the "E" but formatting the decimals to have:

```
 7.98203E-05
```

If someone could show me the light i would really appreciate it.

Comment: http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/format-decimal-number-using-scientific.html or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` ([docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)):

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning
0       Number      Yes         Digit
#       Number      Yes         Digit, zero shows as absent
.       Number      Yes         Decimal separator or monetary decimal separator 
E       Number      Yes         Separates mantissa and exponent in scientific notation.
```

For example:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#####E00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(7.9820892389040892803E-05));
System.out.println(formatter.format(7.98E-05));
```

Output:

```
7.98209E-05
7.98E-05
```

Note that when you use the `#` the trailing zeros will not be printed. If you always want five digits after the decimal point you should use `0`:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00000E00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(7.98E-05));
```

Output:

```
7.98000E-05
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [String Formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

The format you need would be `%.5E` (= precision 5 in uppercase scientific notation)

Example: `System.out.printf("%.5E", 5/17d);` which prints `2.94118E-01`

Answer (score 0):

Use a DeciamlFormat object...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double amount = 7.9820892389040892803E-05;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00000E0");
        System.out.println(df.format(amount));
}
```

Results:

[image]